# Is there still a bug in IE8 with jQuery droppables?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, droppable

I have a page which has a tabbed view which contains 3 sortable columns below it.  Currently, the tabs don't have any jQuery code associated.  I gave them all the droppable class, however, and now in IE if a piece of content is dragged between columns and then moved again, jQuery blows up while trying (i think) to access the parentNode in the DOM. I found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui/browse_thread/thread/6f69bdf753bf7d40) article which discusses a similar problem, but is a year old and refers to IE7.  Does any one know if there are similar issues in IE8?

UPDATE: The bug is somehow related to UpdatePanels...each of the columns is a seperate updatepanel, and if I remove the updatepanels the page works normally.

Comment: Can you mockup a demo at jsbin.com or pastebin.me

Comment: All the draggable and droppable demos from UI docs works fine in IE8.

Comment: I think the bug is somehow related to updatepanels, i'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: good idea, remove all update panels period!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if anyone is still looking at this, but what I ended up doing was setting up the droppables during the sortable's start event, and destroying them during the sortable's stop event. This fixed the IE issue.